# Strict refs error when working with hash reference

Tags: perl, reference, dereference

I'm including code that I've verified illustrates my problem. My objective is to take a hash returned from a database query simulated here as %r (which contains the numerical indexing) and use the value of the "name" field as the key in the receiving hash. (This hash will contain results from multiple queries.)

I feel it's likely I'm doing something stupid with references and dereferencing. I'd really like to try to grasp the concepts at work here. Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -T

use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;
my %r = (
  '1' => {
    name => 'Harry',
    desc => 'Prince',
  },
);

MergeHash(\%hash,\%r);
foreach my $name (keys %hash) {
  print "name = $name, desc = $hash{$name}{desc}\n"; # EDIT: REVISED
}
exit;

sub MergeHash {
  my $h = shift; # reference to receiving hash
  my $r = shift; # reference to giving hash
  foreach my $i (keys %{$r}) {
    $$h{name} = $$r{$i}{name} || 'Unknown'; # okay
    $$h{name}{desc} = $$r{$i}{desc} || 'Unknown'; # Can't use string ("Harry") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at ./test.pl line 25.
  }
}
```

Edit: As requested, the output (also indicated in the code above as comments):

```
Can't use string ("Harry") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at ./test.pl line 25.
```

Edit #2: Revised print line (in code above) to make it clear the structure desired in %hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$$h{name}{desc}
```

is more clearly written as

```
$h->{name}{desc}
```

which is short for

```
$h->{name}->{desc}
```

As this makes clearer, the value of `$h->{name}` is being used as a hash reference (just like the value of `$h` was a moment before), but it contains a string.

---

All you need to do replace `name` with the actual name, because that's what you want the key to be.

```
for my $i (keys(%$r)) {
    $h->{ $r->{$i}{name} }{desc} = $r->{$i}{desc};
}
```

We don't actually need `$i`, so let's simplify.

```
for my $row (values(%$r)) {
    $h->{ $row->{name} }{desc} = $row->{desc};
}
```

---

The problem with the above is that it doesn't lend itself to more than one field per row. The following deals with that better:

```
for my $row (values(%$r)) {
    $h->{ $row->{name} } = {
       desc => $row->{desc},
       # ...
    };
}
```

Buy why build a new hash when could just the one we already have?

```
for my $row (values(%$r)) {
    $h->{ $row->{name} } = $row;
}
```

Comment: I followed all of the edits in your answer with great interest. The final snippet in your answer does exactly what I'd hoped. I think I even see why. After first I thought it was magic, since "desc" isn't mentioned at all. But I think what it does is traverse all the values in the hash, so I don't have to single it out. This is actually what I was going to work on next. I learned a lot from both you and jeff6times7 so thanks!

Comment: Remember, the values of the hash `%$r` are references to hashes (e.g. the reference returned by `{
    name => 'Harry',
    desc => 'Prince',
  }`, so it's doing `$h->{ $row->{name} } = {
    name => 'Harry',
    desc => 'Prince',
  }`, exception using the same hash instead of making a copy.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to overwrite the receiving hash's member with all of the data from the giving hash, then the following code will work.

```
sub MergeHash {
   my $h = shift; # reference to receiving hash
   my $r = shift; # reference to giving hash
   while (my ($k, $v) = each %$r) {
      $h->{$k} = $v;
   }
}
```

The problem is that $$h assumes $h is a reference to a SCALAR and it is not, it is a reference to a HASH, you usually see people either dereference the hash while referring to one its members as I have done above. The other way is to declare a copy of the hash like this, but which would not work for your use case:

```
my %copyofh = %$h;
```